# Issues creating AlloyDB

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-alloydb

Creating new AlloyDB instances has been failing for the past 24 hours. It was working fine a few days ago

```
# creating the cluster works
gcloud beta alloydb clusters create dev-cluster \
    --password=$PG_RAND_PW \
    --network=$PRIVATE_NETWORK_NAME \
    --region=us-east4 \
    --project=${PROJECT_ID}

# creating primary instance fails
gcloud beta alloydb instances create devdb \
    --instance-type=PRIMARY \
    --cpu-count=2 \
    --region=us-east4 \
    --cluster=dev-cluster \
    --project=${PROJECT_ID}
```

Error message is

```
Operation ID: operation-1660168834702-5e5ea2da8dcd1-d96bdabb-4c686076
Creating instance...failed.   
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.alloydb.instances.create) an internal error has occurred
```

Creating from the console fails also

[image]

I have tried from a complete new project also and it still fails.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This appears to be a Google issue. You'll need to contact Google Cloud support or file an issue on Google's public [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Comment: Hey rossco, just checking in to confirm if this resolved itself. AlloyDB being a preview product isn't always fully provisioned in all our regions, so I think you may have hit a stock out issue, which should have resolved itself (you could also test this by trying to create a cluster in other regions, but of course this may be an issue in multiple regions until we fully stock it up when we're out of preview).

Comment: Hi @GabeWeiss Confirming I can create the cluster and DB in us-east4 again now

Comment: Woo! Glad to hear. Thanks for confirming rossco.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to replicate your issue and it seems that this is due to AlloyDB for PostgreSQL is still in preview and we may encounter some bugs and errors according to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/alloydb/docs/overview):

> This product is covered by the [Pre-GA Offerings Terms](https://cloud.google.com/terms/service-terms#0) of the Google Cloud Terms of Service. Pre-GA products might have limited support, and changes to pre-GA products might not be compatible with other pre-GA versions. For more information, see the [launch stage descriptions](https://cloud.google.com/products#product-launch-stages).

What worked on my end is following this documentation on [creating a cluster and its primary instance](https://cloud.google.com/alloydb/docs/cluster-create#console) using the console. This step will create both the cluster and its primary instance at the same time. Please see my screenshot below for your reference:

[image: 5]

As you can see the instance under the cluster `my-cluster` has an error and was not created however the instance `devdb` was created following the link that I provided above.

It would also be best to [raise this as an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/) as per @DazWilkin's comment if this issue would still persist in the future.